# What needs to be done to ArcGIS Server if the server machine/host name is changed?

Tags: arcgis-server

We have a Windows Server 2008 where ArcGIS Server 10 was installed.  Not much has been done with the machine yet, but the name of the machine had to be changed after the ArcGIS installation.  The old server name was DAYTONA and the new name of the server is PIGIRON (names changed to protect the innocent).

In the server activity log there is a message:
"Machine daytona is not a valid server container. Machine daytona is not found."

I also see an error in the system event log that reads:
"DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer daytona using any of the configured protocols."

I found a reference to daytona in the file C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Server10.0\server\system\Server.dat, but when I remove the machine reference in this file, save it, and restart the SOM, the machine reference gets put back into this file.  This leads me to believe that there are other things that need to be updated because of the server name change.

I found something on ESRI's website about doing this on a Linux or AIX box and the three step solution was uninstall ArcGIS, rename the server, install ArcGIS.  I might end up doing that, but thought there might be a way to do it with out reinstalling everything.

The SOC is not listed in ArcCatalog under this GIS Server.  We tried adding it anyway, and then removing it, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be sufficient to just re-run both Post-Installs. If that doesn't do it, you'll likely need a full reinstall.

Comment: I left that part out, we did re-run the post installs and still have the DCOM error message and the server activity log still shows the error about looking for the old server name.  Instead of removing the old name from the Server.dat config file, it kept it and added the new one, so now there are two.  I feel a complete reinstall on the way, which would be faster than trying to figure this out.

Comment: It might be worth taking a look at how AGS works in EC2.  By default EC2 instances get a new hostname when they restart.  This meant Esri had to devise a script that would gracefully re-configure AGS.  I think that script is available as a text file (powershell?).

Comment: Never mind, I see AGS on EC2 has a startup script that calls ArcGISServerStartUp.exe to do the renaming, but my local install of AGS doesn't have this exe.

Comment: For reference, help topic on how to perform the steps: http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/34514

Comment: Since it was early rnough in the process of setting up the server, it was just faster and easier to reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

For me, just full reinstall AGS 10 for Java plataform works.

Remove, install and run post install.

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop arcgis server service
2. modify server.dat
3. start service